# How to create better Kubernetes architecture for multiple servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I'm new in Kubernetes:

I have a multiple independent servers, they are based on spring boot java.
Each server has a separate independent database, where  database connection details are written in application.yml.

And I was wondering if i deploy in Kubernetes,
should I have a let say 15 different deployments , basically for each application.yml?

Could you please suggest the general flow or picture?

Answer (score 1):

Flexibility comes when there is less or no dependency, so yes each service should be deployed and managed with its own deployment. So deployments just manage pod, and the pod is the smallest unit of the Kubernetes application, for example, let's say we have two services login and user service. Both have different container image so we need two different pods which mean two different deployments.

It will help to scale, rollout, clean and update independently. Plus in future, if you place monitoring etc it help you to identify object from the deployment which having issue.

[kubernetes-deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)

Services like [ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which work based on [GitOps](https://www.gitops.tech/) approach, sync applications from the git repository so in that case, it is also easier to sync applications independently.

In addition to that, Better to use a [helm](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/) each service will represent a helm chart.

Comment: Thank you , one follow up question. 
lets say if i have 10 regions in AWS. Each region have separate VPC's. 
So i need to create 10 pods with deployments. Does it mean 10 pods will be placed in 10 nodes?

Comment: if different region then yes,  which can be multi-region cluster